# Apply external stylesheet to a particular section

Tags: css, css-selectors

On my website I allow user-generated style sheets to be used. But I don't want those styles to affect the the whole website, just a separate section/div. Is there way to do that, without going through the whole custom style sheet and adding my div selector to every css rule?
For example if a user has:

```
a, span{color:white;}
div{padding:10px;}
```

Right now I have to parse it out and replace to

```
#mySection a, #mySection span{color:white;}
#mySection div{padding:10px;}
```

Comment: I think you have to parse the CSS properly (really hard), or use an `iframe`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately there isn't. There is no CSS equivalent to the `<base>` tag or similar that would limit the scope of a CSS rule.

You will have to prepend every rule with the element(s) you want to apply them to, or load the user styled content in an iframe.

Comment: That's what I thought, could you tell if the solution above is okay or there may be some potential holes in it?

Comment: @negative: First question - do you strip `!important`?

Comment: @negative the solution above looks okay to me. If you prepend every rule with `#mySection`, I can't think of any holes

Comment: @thirtydot no, but does it really mater since 'modified' selectors have a scope of `#mySection`?

Comment: @negative: It depends how robust your "'modified' selector" parsing is. For instance, how well would it stand up against this sort of stuff *(for example)*: http://centricle.com/ref/css/filters/ - it depends on how much you care about stopping *malicious users* being bad.

Comment: @thirtydot nice link! Indeed, the `@import` directive is one thing to be aware of (= strip). Also, testing against shenanigans like `/*/*//*/property:value;/* *` is a good idea